# Multiple rows by value from cell

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Using SQL Server:

I have one table with different items and quantities
By the quantity a need to multiple rows to have every piece on different line

Raw table:

| Code | QTY |
| --- | --- |
| Item1 | 1 |
| Item2 | 3 |
| Item3 | 2 |

Result I need:

| Code | QTY |
| --- | --- |
| Item1 | 1 |
| Item2 | 1 |
| Item2 | 1 |
| Item2 | 1 |
| Item3 | 1 |
| Item3 | 1 |

Already tried with FOR EACH, WITH but without any result.
I need it just like SELECT without INSERTS and temporary tables etc.
What is also option to make a view.

Best try was:

```
WITH Numbers(Number) AS (
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Number + 1 
    FROM Numbers
    WHERE Number <= (
        SELECT 
        SUM(QRY1.QTY) FROM QRY1
    )
)
SELECT DTBL.Code, DTBL.QTY
FROM Numbers
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT
        Items as Code
        , 1 as QTY
    FROM QRY1
) DTBL
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you provide your sample data as DDL+DML you make it much easier to assist. Also please do show us your best attempt. Hint recursive CTE or tally table join.

Comment: make use of a `tally` table. `Raw r INNER JOIN Tally t ON t.number BETWEEN 1 AND r.QTY`

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

This generates numbered rows:

```
with cte as (
  select 1 as rn
  union all
  select rn + 1
  from cte
  where rn < 100
)
```

Then we just join it to your data where the number is between 1 and your quantity

```
SELECT r.Code, 1 as Qty, *
FROM 
  raw r
  INNER JOIN cte ON cte.rn BETWEEN 1 AND r.Qty
```

If you have more than 100 qty, you'll need to generate more rows - search for "option maxrecursion" to find how to up the limit

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using recursive CTE.

```sql
DECLARE @table table(code varchar(10), qty int)

insert into @table values
('Item1',   1),
('Item2',   3),
('Item3',   2);

;WITH CTE_CODE AS
(
SELECT  CODE, 1 AS CNT FROM @table
union all
SELECT c.code, CNT+1 as cnt 
from cte_code as c
WHERE EXISTS (
select * from @table where code = c.code and qty > c.cnt)
)
SELECT code, 1 as qty FROM CTE_CODE
order by code
```

| code | qty |
| --- | --- |
| Item1 | 1 |
| Item2 | 1 |
| Item2 | 1 |
| Item2 | 1 |
| Item3 | 1 |
| Item3 | 1 |

Comment: This is also working like I need, thanks!